# Registration form not processed to database properly (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web

I tried to build a login/registration page ..the register page worked perfectly few hours back and now it is not processing ..when i click the register button ,it reloads the same register page and the form is not processed to database ...the register page is in site root folder and the sql is query is passed from another php file class.newuser.php which is inside root/models/class.newuser.php ...how to solve this problem please help me out !!thanks in advance

enter code here
'

```
       <?php
      require_once("models/config.php");
       if(isUserLoggedIn()) { header("Location: index.php"); die(); }
       ?>


         <?php
    //Forms posted
        if(!empty($_POST))
        {
$errors = array();
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$username = trim($_POST["username"]);
$password = trim($_POST["password"]);
$confirm_pass = trim($_POST["passwordc"]);

//Perform some validation
//Feel free to edit / change as required

if(minMaxRange(5,25,$username))
{
    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_CHAR_LIMIT",array(5,25));
}
if(minMaxRange(8,50,$password) && minMaxRange(8,50,$confirm_pass))
{
    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASS_CHAR_LIMIT",array(8,50));
}
else if($password != $confirm_pass)
{
    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASS_MISMATCH");
}
if(!isValidemail($email))
{
    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_INVALID_EMAIL");
}
//End data validation
if(count($errors) == 0)
{   
        //Construct a user object
        $user = new User($username,$password,$email);

        //Checking this flag tells us whether there were any errors such as possible  data duplication occured
        if(!$user->status)
        {
            if($user->username_taken) $errors[] =  lang("ACCOUNT_USERNAME_IN_USE",array($username));
            if($user->email_taken)    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_EMAIL_IN_USE",array($email));       
        }
        else
        {
            //Attempt to add the user to the database, carry out finishing  tasks like emailing the user (if required)
            if(!$user->userPieAddUser())
            {
                if($user->mail_failure) $errors[] = lang("MAIL_ERROR");
                if($user->sql_failure)  $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
            }
        }
}
        if(count($errors) == 0) 
        {
        if($emailActivation)
        {
        $message = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE2");
        } else {
        $message = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE1");
        }
        }
         }
?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Registration | <?php echo $websiteName; ?> </title>
 <?php require_once("head_inc.php"); ?>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="modal-ish">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <h2>Sign Up</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <div id="success">
  <p><?php echo $message ?></p>
  </div>
  <div id="regbox">
 <form name="newUser" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <p>
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label>Re-type Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  </p>
   <p>
   <label>Email:</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" />
    </p>
   </div>           
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="new" id="newfeedform"       value="Register" />
   </div>  
   </form>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <p style="margin-top:30px; text-align:center;"><a href="login.php">Login</a> /  <a href="forgot-password.php">Forgot Password?</a> / <a href="<?php echo $websiteUrl;  ?>">Home Page</a></p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Check weather you get proper $_POST variable values ?

Comment: where your session is starting?

Comment: show us `var_dump($_POST)` in the conditional `if(!empty($_POST))`

Comment: i am really sorry . i am a beginner in this .can you please be specific ...so that i can find and tell you ..please help me

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the html form
2. make an if statement for when the submit button is clicked
3. enter you validations.
4. when validations are passed make a connection to you database
5. now make your query

This should be working good if not you might have a typo somewhere in your query.
Note: Make sure you can see php error in your browser that way you would know what is wrong

Comment: the current format is absolutely correct...if the values are not passed into the database ..then what's the problem...queries are passed perfectly ..html and php is fine ..but still it is not working

Comment: try to make a form with one text box save that to a database see i that works if not than you web environment has an issue

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `</form>`
Also I don't see a query that you are writing it to a database.
All I see is that you are passing it to variables.

Correct me If I am wrong.
English is not my first language and I can only see part of your project so I am sorry if I miss understood something I am just trying to help.

Comment: </form> is there ..it is after div tag..as i mentioned in my query that database queries are passed from class.newuser.php ..please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: but you are telling your form to go to it self do you have the query in a different file if so try putting everything in one file just to test it and you will have everything by hand

Comment: it was working perfectly few hours back and now it is not working ..i didn't change anything inside the code ..where exactly i need to put the sql queries in the above code ..please tell me exact place to place the code or else is it possible to refer from externally ..please reply thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: the name of the password and retype password are the same, you need to differentiate those:

```
  <p>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label>Re-type Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  </p>
```

From what I see from you php code from top, you the second field has the name of "passwordc". So you need to change it to:

```
  <p>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label>Re-type Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="passwordc" />
  </p>
```

In addition, I would also verify to see if a user has clicked the button, so only then you would register the user, something like:

```
if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['new'])
{
    $errors = array();
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    $confirm_pass = trim($_POST["passwordc"]);
    ....
```

Comment: thanks for showing interest and answering me ..i changed into passwordc before itself while checking. and also the if(!empty....)...that one too ...its not working still ..help me out